# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'demoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app1 = angular.module('sample', []);
app1.controller('DemoCtrl',
  function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    var codes;
    $scope.items = [];
    $interval((function() {
      if (codes && codes.length > 0) {
        $scope.items.push({
          text: codes.shift()
        });
        if ($scope.items.length > 10) {
          return codes.push($scope.items.shift().text);
        }
      }
    }), 300);
    $http.get(location.href)
      .success(function(contents) {
        var each;
        codes = [];
        contents = contents.split('\n');
        while (contents.length > 0) {
          each = contents.shift();
          if (each.trim()) {
            codes.push(each.substr(0, 80));
          }
        }
        return codes;
      });
  });
```

**Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'demoCtrl' is not a**

Comment: possibly letter case issue? `demoCtrl`vs `DemoCtrl`

Answer (score 1):

Your controller name is `'DemoCtrl'` not `'demoCtrl'` which you probably are using in an `ng-controller` or other component  assignment.

Synchronize them so cases are the same